# R For loop with if statement to Apply format

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, sapply

Say I have a for loop that looks like this.

```
person <- c("Mike", "Kim", "Fred", "Steve", "Quail", "bean")

sleep <- c(5, 10, 3, 7, 1, 5)


dat <- data.frame(person, sleep)

for (i in 1:length(dat$person)) {
 if (dat$sleep[i] >= 7) {
   dat$fatigue[i] <- 0
 }
 if (dat$sleep[i] > 5 & dat$sleep[i] < 7) {
   dat$fatigue[i] <- 1
 }
 if (dat$sleep[i] >= 3 & dat$sleep[i] <= 5) {
   dat$fatigue[i] <- 2
 }
 if (dat$sleep[i] < 3) {
  dat$fatigue[i] <- 3
 }
}
```

How would I write this for loop with the if statements using the apply functionality of R?

I am rather new to using this and any help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Was it intentional that you have `>=3 & <=5` then `>5 & <7` ? If not, then `?cut` is probably worth a look - e.g. - `cut(sleep, c(0,3,5,7,Inf))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `case_when` from the `dplyr` library

```
dat$fatigue <- case_when(
    dat$sleep < 3 ~ 3,
    dat$sleep >= 3 & dat$sleep <= 5 ~ 2,
    dat$sleep > 5 & dat$sleep < 7 ~ 1,
    dat$sleep >= 7 ~ 0,
    TRUE ~ -1
)
```

Note that `case_when()`, like many functions in R, is already vectorized.  Therefore, you don't need to use an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: I see. What does the TRUE ~ -1 mean at the end?

Comment: @mrsquid The `TRUE` case at the end would be reached if none of the other conditions matched.  This should not happen ideally (except maybe in the case of an `NA` value), but if it did, then `sleep` would be assigned to `-1` for that row.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use nested ifelse this solution can be useful using baseR

```
person <- c("Mike", "Kim", "Fred", "Steve", "Quail", "bean")

sleep <- c(5, 10, 3, 7, 1, 5)

dat <- data.frame(person, sleep)

dat$fatigue <- ifelse(dat$sleep < 3,3,ifelse(dat$sleep >= 3 & dat$sleep <= 5, 2,ifelse(dat$sleep > 5 & dat$sleep < 7,1,ifelse(dat$sleep >= 7, 0,"NA"))))
)
```